# taskkill' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file

Tags: cmd.exe, node.js

Received an error while running `$ backstop test` on my node.js cmd.

```
'taskkill' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file'
```

Can't seem to find a solution or this.

Comment: What is the result of `where taskkill`? On e.g. Windows 7, this file should be located under `C:\Windows\System32\taskill.exe`.